# Finding the incrementer and the Total Cost of a code?

Tags: data-structures, complexity-theory

This was a quiz last week. I thought the answer of the question below is Line:3 . However, the Instructor told me that Line 4 is better. I still don't get why? and leads to another question, how do I know my best increment ?

[image]

The second question I would like to ask, **How to represent the cost of the running code below using Summations?** I've searched a lot and all I find was finding the complexity of a code which is not related to this.

I hope you guys clear everything to me.

Comment: Why not ask the instructor? I think line 3 is ok too...

Comment: I have a homework to solve and deadline on Saturday, and it's based on these foundations. It's weekend already. yes it's okay but he said it's better to use line 4 and I clearly have no idea how to represent the cost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you multiply an integer by 2 the compiler will automatically translate it to a right shift operation (which is very efficient).  Also, it is more expensive to compare floating point numbers than it is to compare integers. Since the number of times line 4 is going to be executed is the same as the number of times line 3 gets executed, line 4 will be the best representative of the total cost.

The total cost of the code

```
= total cost of comparing i with n and incrementing i + 
  total cost of comparing j with n and right shifting j + 
  total cost of comparing two floats + 
  total cost of incrementing a float

<= c1*n + c2*n*n/2 + c3*n*n/2 + c4\sum_{1 <= i <= n, 1 <= k <= n/2}d(i,2k), 
                 where d(i, j) is 1 if array[i] > array[j] and 0 otherwise.

<= c1*n + c2*n^2  + c3n^2 + c4n^2

<= c*n^2 for some constant c
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer. However, I'm not sure If I'm following you in the last 3 lines. Anyway to write it without codes.

Comment: c_1, c_2, c_3, c_4 are constants. May be you are confused about the term after c_4. This term corresponds to line 5 and is counting the number of pairs (i,j) such that j is an even number and array[i] > array[j].